# Printing date without time

Tags: sql-server, typescript, react-native, date

I'm still new to react(Typescript) and I want to print a date I got from the database but without the time.

here is my Interface:

```
interface Games {
g_Id: number;
g_Title: string;
g_Genre: string;
g_Plattform: string;
g_ReleaseDate: Date;
g_Price: number;}
```

---

and my output method:

```
private static renderGamesTable(games: Games[]) {
    console.log(games)
    return <table className='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
                <th>Plattform</th>
                <th>Release Date</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {games.map(games =>
                <tr key={games.g_Id}>
                    <td>{games.g_Title}</td>
                    <td>{games.g_Genre}</td>
                    <td>{games.g_Plattform}</td>
                    <td>{games.g_ReleaseDate}</td>
                    <td>{games.g_Price}</td>
                </tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
    </table>;
}
```

---

as well as the database design

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Games] (
[G_Id]          INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[G_Genre]       NVARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
[G_Plattform]   NVARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
[G_Price]       DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
[G_ReleaseDate] DATETIME2 (7)   NOT NULL,
[G_Title]       NVARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Games] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([G_Id] ASC));
```

I'm using .Net core and MS-Sql (i haven't added the fetch method and the controllers since I didn't think they were important, so feel free to ask, if they were).

---

What I've tried so far is:

1. Changing the datatype in the Database
2. Trying to convert the Date (using getyear or toDateString ...etc)
3. I've tried changing the format using moment
4. Creating a new datetype that only accept the date

---

Nothing seems to work so far (It could be since I'm new I'm missing something obvious, so sorry about that :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dateformat` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat) for this.

```
import * as dateFormat from 'dateformat';

const formatDate = (dt) => dateFormat(dt, "mm/dd/yyyy");


<td>{formatDate(games.g_ReleaseDate)}</td>
```

Or could you try this.

```
const formatDate = (dt:Date) => dt.toLocaleDateString()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked just fine !
p.s : in typescript i had to import it like this ` import * as dateFormat from 'dateformat'; ` .

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked any documentation about the Date type?
[Date TypeScript interface on microsoft github](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_es5_d_.date.html)

From what I understood from your question you want to modify the date object for output reasons:

```
<td>{games.g_ReleaseDate}</td>
```

From what I found you should only need to add

```
.toLocaleDateString()
```

Example for TS online: [Date TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=16&pln=2&pc=36#code/G4QwTgBAJgjBC8EB2BTA7hAIiALigFAJQDcAUAMYD2SAzpQDYoB09lA5vrEzpQDKXkQjbHgDKOMAEskHQoVKkA9IogAVShEbgkEALaUwKCCABGlAK44IOABZH6IGeZBsUAGgjl6k8gGtjZsBG0hAARACiAB4gugAOjDShEAZhAOo2uADkNBAAcuihTEoqAPK2KGBokjTuEK5WNDjgeFAQJgCeEIb6wNJs1nY1npS6uihIODmOreUQaAb0rdUQ7RaQ8SDtbGAWSFBFEBBAA)

Comment: I did read about the Date type and the problem is whenever i try to use something like "games.g_ReleaseDate.toLocaleDateString()" i get an error saying that it's not allowed to be a function, it does not work even when i try to define a new varaiable "new Date().toDateString()" which is the reason i'm confused rn despite me googling for the last hour or so